# Exception inserting tab page on a second form

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

My primary form launches a secondary form, which contains an owner-drawn tab control. The primary form then calls a public function in the secondary form to insert a tab page at a given index. I am consistently getting this exception inside my tabcontrol's `DrawItem` event handler:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'InvalidArgument=Value of '2' is not valid for 'index'.
Parameter name: index'
```

in this code:

```
private void tabControl_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
     TabPage thisTab = tabControl.TabPages[e.Index];
...
```

The relevant call stack is:

```
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.TabControl.GetTabPage(int index)  Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.TabControl.TabPageCollection.this[int].get(int index) Unknown
>   tabControl_DrawItem(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs e) Line 751   C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.TabControl.OnDrawItem(System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs e)   Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.TabControl.WmReflectDrawItem(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)  Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.TabControl.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)   Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam)  Unknown
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.SendMessage(int msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam)  Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ReflectMessageInternal(System.IntPtr hWnd, ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmOwnerDraw(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)   Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmDrawItem(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)   Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)   Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam)  Unknown
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)   Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.DefWndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)   Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.TabControl.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)   Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam)  Unknown
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)   Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.DefWndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)   Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.TabControl.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)    Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)   Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam)  Unknown
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.TabControl.InsertItem(int index, System.Windows.Forms.TabPage tabPage)    Unknown
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.TabControl.TabPageCollection.Insert(int index, System.Windows.Forms.TabPage tabPage)  Unknown
```

Inside the public routine in the second form which is invoked by the primary form, I'm inserting a new tab page at index=1 of the tab control, and the tab control by default starts with two tabs. At the time of this exception, the `TabPages` member of the tab control only has the two default tab pages, and I am in the call stack of the public function that has already created the third tab page (at index=1) via the `TabPages.Insert(<index>, <TabPage>)` routine.

This started happening when I changed the secondary form to be non-dialog (meaning from the parent I call `Show()` instead of `ShowDialog()`), so that both forms could be interacted with at the same time. I tried adding focus to the second form prior to changing the tab pages, but it did not help.

Comment: please provide a minimal example(during that you may find the root cause yourself).

Comment: You need to add a Tab Page to the control for each tab page to the instance of the control.  Error indicates that you do not have 3 (index 2) tab pages.  The exception looks recursive that the exception is triggering and second exception of the same type.